# Set and Get an array of Doubles

Tags: java, arrays

I'm very new to Java and confused about getting an setting arrays.  Just super basic code I want to update the array of grades in the Student Class.  I setGrades with the double[] input array, but when I call getGrades it returns junk: `[D@610455d6`.

I know it's something super easy I'm missing

```
public class Student
{
    private double[] grades;

    public void setGrades(double[] grades)
    {
        this.grades = grades;
    }

    public double[] getGrades()
    {
        return grades;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] input = {87.54, 67.45};
        Student ted = new Student();
        ted.setGrades(input);
        System.out.println(ted.getGrades());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To print the values of your array you have to loop throw your array and print value by value, but there are a better way so instead of :

```
System.out.println(ted.getGrades());
```

you have to use `Arrays.toString(array)` like this :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ted.getGrades()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you return an array.

```
getGrades()[0]
```

gets the first element in your Array

Answer (score 0):

Printing an array in Java returns its hash code, which is what `[D@610455d6` is. You'll either need to specify an index `in getGrades()` or use `Arrays.toString(ted.getGrades())` to turn the array into a printable format.

Comment: The number is the hashcode, not the memory location.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in Java override a function called `toString()`, which returns whatever String representation of the object is defined in the class, and `toString()` is called implicitly when you pass an instance of an object to the print method. A primitive Array does not return a very useful String representation--just the hashCode used when hashing the object for placement in (for example) a HashMap. The `Arrays` utility class, however, includes a more useful `toString()` function that you must call explicitly, passing the array as an argument.

```
Arrays.toString(ted.getGrades());
```

I suggest figuring how to access individual elements of the grades array without returning it though. It's commonly a bad idea to leave a way to access internal object data without control. You could decide to clobber the internal array somewhere else in your program if you save a reference to it. One possibility is to pass the grades array to your object constructor and have that constructor do a full copy of that array. Then, have a getter and setter for individual array index accesses instead of access to the entire array.